# laravel l5-repository Class Not found Exception

Tags: laravel-5

I'm developing using Laravel 5.2 and l5-repository 2.1. I created some repositories that worked fine, but after a while, I got back to project and self-updated the composer and created some new views and a new model and corresponding repositories. but get the Class not found an exception. as I move the new Model from Models folder to repositories folder the error disappears. can anyone help?

ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class App\Repositories\Tour does not exist

and this is the stack trace:

> in Container.php line 734 at ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Repositories\Tour') in Container.php line 734 at Container->build('App\Repositories\Tour', array()) in Container.php line 629 at Container->make('App\Repositories\Tour', array()) in Application.php line 697 at Application->make('App\Repositories\Tour') in BaseRepository.php line 176 at BaseRepository->makeModel() in BaseRepository.php line 92 at BaseRepository->__construct(object(Application)) at ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(array(object(Application))) in Container.php line 779 at Container->build('App\Repositories\TourRepositoryEloquent', array()) in Container.php line 629 at Container->make('App\Repositories\TourRepositoryEloquent', array()) in Application.php line 697 at Application->make('App\Repositories\TourRepositoryEloquent', array()) in Container.php line 230 at Container->Illuminate\Container{closure}(object(Application), array()) in Container.php line 731 at Container->build(object(Closure), array()) in Container.php line 629 at Container->make('App\Repositories\TourRepository', array()) in Application.php line 697 at Application->make('App\Repositories\TourRepository') in Container.php line 849 at Container->resolveClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 804 at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter), object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 775 at Container->build('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController', array()) in Container.php line 629 at Container->make('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController', array()) in Application.php line 697 at Application->make('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67 at ControllerDispatcher->makeController('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 52 at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController', 'welcome') in Route.php line 174 at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140 at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724 at Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which might trigger this problem. First is a bad class cache. Try an `artisan cache:clear`.

The second is that Laravel's autoloader looks for a class based on its namespace. If you're not updating the namespace when looking for the file, Laravel will probably fail to find it.

Answer (score 0):

In repository implementation class TourRepositoryEloquent the model function returns the Tour::class. I changed it to "App\Models\Tour" and it works fine right now. Am I missing anything like configuration?